# Rails group by foreign key with custom rules

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following `tables`/`models` in my helpdesk module.

**status.rb**

```
has_many :tickets
```

**Statuses table**

```
id         name
----------------------
1          New
2          Assigned
3          In progress
4          Finished
5          Closed
6          Cancelled
```

**ticket.rb**

```
belongs_to :status
```

**Tickets table**

```
id    status_id   subject    customer_id
----------------------------------------
1     1           Ticket 1   1
2     1           Ticket 2   1
3     2           Ticket 3   1
4     3           Ticket 4   1
5     4           Ticket 5   1
6     3           Ticket 6   1
7     1           Ticket 7   1
8     2           Ticket 8   1
```

For helpdesk team, i need to show tickets count by status.

This would work for it,

```
Ticket.all.joins(:status).group("statuses.name").count
 => {"New" => 3, "Assigned" => 2, "In progress" => 2, "Finished" => 1}
```

Now the problem is, I want to show `Assigned` and `In progress` as single group, `Active`, to customers.

The result should look like this,

```
=> {"New" => 3, "Active" => 4, "Finished" => 1}
```

How can I get this result using?

Comment: I suggest to not do it in SQL, just have a method that converts first hash to final hash.

Comment: `status_frequencies.except('Assigned', 'In progress').merge('Active' => status_frequencies['Assigned'] + status_frequencies['In progress'])`

Comment: I agree with @MikDiet. Adding this logic in SQL will make it difficult from messy and prone to future maintainance. Doing it in ruby method will be a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to call the `.all` method
2. Now the real solution, is a hack-ish way but it works and is tested.
   `# my_var is the variable in which you fetch the records`
   `my_var['Assigned'] += my_var['In progress']`
   `my_var['Active'] = my_var.delete 'Assigned'`
   `my_var.delete 'In progress'`